# DolphinDB: multiply a vector with each row of a table?

Tags: datatable, data-processing, dolphindb

How can I multiply a vector of length 4 by each row of a table with 100 rows and 4 columns?

For example, I have a vector：

[vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL5C5.png)

The table is shown as follow:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5S1s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, table in DolphinDB is processed by rows (each row is a dictionary), and matix and tuple by columns with higher-order functions.

Assume that the vector and table are as follows:

```
v=1 2 3
t=table(1..100 as a, 1..100 as b, 1..100 as c)
```

Processing by row:

```
each(mul{v}, t)
```

Processing by column (two ways):

- Use the `table.values()` function to convert the table to a tuple, with
  each column of the table as an element of the tuple.
- Use the `flip` function to converts the table into a dictionary, with
  the column name as key and the data as value.

---

```
each(*, t.values(), v) //return a matrix
t.flip().mul(v).flip() //return a table(supported since 2.00.9 and 1.30.21）
```